# Highlight cells in grid, and demarcate row and column headers

Tags: grid-layouts

I have a 25x25 grid of a function `T[x]` expressed in terms of variables `x` and `R`. The output is a grid of 0s and 1s:

```
Grid[MapThread[
  Prepend, {Prepend[
    FullSimplify[Table[T[x], {x, 25}, {R, 25}]], {"R=1", "R=2", "R=3",
      "R=4", "R=5", "R=6", "R=7", "R=8", "R=9", "R=10", "R=11", 
     "R=12", "R=13", "R=14", "R=15", "R=16", "R=17", "R=18", "R=19", 
     "R=20", "R=21", "R=22", "R=23", "R=24", "R=25"}], {"", "x=1", 
    "x=2", "x=3", "x=4", "x=5", "x=6", "x=7", "x=8", "x=9", "x=10", 
    "x=11", "x=12", "x=13", "x=14", "x=15", "x=16", "x=17", "x=18", 
    "x=19", "x=20", "x=21", "x=22", "x=23", "x=24", "x=25"}}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

I want all instances of `T[x]=1` to appear in bold, and I want a thicker line beneath the column headers and to the right of the row headers.

I can't find anything that works on this site or in the Mathematica documentation. And as a noob to Mathematica, I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: You can use `Table[T[x], {x, 25}, {R, 25}] /. 1 -> Style[1, Bold]` to make the ones bold. Moreover, look up the `FrameStyle` option of `Grid` (see the documentation of `Grid`, section "Options", subsection `FrameStyle`).

Comment: Will look into FrameStyle. I'd tried Style[1, Bold], but hadn't spotted the space after /. Working now.

Answer (score 2):

```
T[x_, r_] := Mod[x + r, 5]; 
data = MapThread[Prepend, {Prepend[FullSimplify[Table[T[x, R], {x, 25}, {R, 25}]], 
 {"R=1", "R=2", "R=3", "R=4", "R=5", "R=6", "R=7", "R=8", "R=9", "R=10", "R=11",
       "R=12", "R=13", "R=14", "R=15", "R=16", "R=17", "R=18", "R=19",
       "R=20", "R=21", "R=22", "R=23", "R=24", "R=25"}],
 {"", "x=1", "x=2", "x=3", "x=4", "x=5", "x=6", "x=7", "x=8", "x=9", "x=10", 
     "x=11", "x=12", "x=13", "x=14", "x=15", "x=16", "x=17", "x=18", 
     "x=19", "x=20", "x=21", "x=22", "x=23", "x=24", "x=25"}}];

Grid[data /.  1 -> Style[1, Red, Bold], 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> {Thick, Red}}, {2 -> {Thick, Blue}}}]
```

[image]

See: [Documentation >> Dividers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dividers.html)